# Logging warning messages from a Python scrip into an external file not working

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to log warning messages into an external file from a Python script. The file.log remains empty while warning messages are well printed on terminal screen during the script running.

Did I forgot something?

My code looks like this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/home/ubuntu/folder/file.log',
    filemode='a',
    format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.warning('Warning Message 1')
# Code here
logging.warning('Warning Message 2')
# Code here
logging.warning('Warning Message 3')
etc.
```

Comment: It's working for me. I ran your code

Comment: Same here. I ran the code. A file was created with log entries. The only difference was that I used `file.log` as the value for `filename`.

Comment: It worked for me as well, maybe you're checking another file with same name and not which is placed in `filename`

Comment: I don't understand... I think the problem comes from the name of the file, you're right. But I changed it and still no log created.

Comment: Find the problem! I didn't put the logging.basicConfig line at the beginning of my script